# app.post on startpage with Express - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If I implement form handling on the startpage, the system shows an error.

**Code in Express**

```
var http = require('http'),
express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());


// A route for the home page - and the page with a form

app.post('/', function(req, res) {

// Code for Handling the form

});
```

**Form:**

```
<form action="/" method="post"> . . . </form>
```

**Now I get this error:**

Cannot GET /

How can I solve this problem? Some ideas?

**Update for complete route - with Jade**

```
// Set the view engine
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
// Where to find the view files
app.set('views', './views');
// A route for the home page - will render a view
    app.post('/', function(req, res) { 
    res.render('index');     
});
```

**And here the form code:**

```
<form action="/" method="post">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name">
<label>Text</label>
<textarea name="text" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Show us the routes for the homepage and the 'page with a form'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *also* handle `GET` requests, as well as `POST` requests. You need something like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    // Code for handle the form data
});
```